# SQL Query Logic / Conditional WHERE

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm hoping this is a simple question, but I can't figure out how to write my query to get the correct result!

I'm trying to translate a query from a report on our ERP solution (Dynamics NAV) into T-SQL.

I've gotten stuck with a condition of the report. In NAV, it retrieves all of the data using a set of filters - which is fine. After it retrieves the data, it goes through record by record, and 'skips' records which meet 2 conditions.

The condition for records being skipped are:
If "Field A" <> 4 AND "Field B" = 0 THEN SKIP.

The closest i've got to recreating this in T-SQL is:

```
Select *
From t
WHERE [...] AND ( [FieldA] <> 4 AND [FieldB] = 0 )
```

This does not work!

How can I exclude records in T-SQL, only where ((A <> 4) AND (B = 0)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic equivalence `not(A and B) === not(A) or not(B)` is appropriate here.

In this case `A` means `"Field A" <> 4` and `B` means `"Field B" = 0`. So `not(A)` means `"Field A" = 4` and `not(B)` means `"Field B" <> 0`.

Hence

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE [...]
    AND
    (
        [FieldA] = 4 OR
            [FieldB] <> 0
    )
```